# База данных. C# Winforms(Продолжение)

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

[image: я добавил command.ExecuteNonQuery(); теперь выдает ошибку]Теперь у меня не работает команда `INSERT`. Не добавляется запись. 
Вот исходный код:

```
private void buttonInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 

    if (label9.Visible) label9.Visible = false;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxSum1.Text) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBoxSum1.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxData1.Text) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBoxData1.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxType1.Text) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBoxType1.Text))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [Expense] (Sum, Data, Type) VALUES(@Sum, @Data, @Type)", sqlConnection);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Sum", textBoxSum1.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Data", textBoxData1.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Type", textBoxType1.Text);
    }
    else
    {
        label9.Visible = true;
        label9.Text = "Поля 'Cумма' , 'Дата' и 'Категории' должны быть заполнены!";
    }
}

private  async void обновитьToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    listBox1.Items.Clear();
    SqlDataReader sqlReader = null;

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [Expense]", sqlConnection);

    try
    {
        sqlReader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync();

        while (await sqlReader.ReadAsync())
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(Convert.ToString(sqlReader["Id"]) + "    " + Convert.ToString(sqlReader["Sum"]) + "    " + Convert.ToString(sqlReader["Data"]) + "    " + Convert.ToString(sqlReader["Type"]));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), ex.Source.ToString(), MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (sqlReader != null)
            sqlReader.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Что говорит профайлер БД?

Comment: Надо, наверное, все-таки вызвать команду, чтобы она заработала.

Comment: В ошибке ясно написано: column does no allow nulls. В колонку `Id` нельзя вставлять null. Разбирайтесь, откуда оно у вас берётся.

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо что помогли. Я нашёл ошибку. Оказывается я забыл ID идентифицировать

Answer (score 2):

Вы не запустили команду:

```
private void buttonInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (label9.Visible) label9.Visible = false;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxSum1.Text) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBoxSum1.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxData1.Text) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBoxData1.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxType1.Text) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBoxType1.Text))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [Expense] (Sum, Data, Type) VALUES(@Sum, @Data, @Type)", sqlConnection);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Sum", textBoxSum1.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Data", textBoxData1.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Type", textBoxType1.Text);
        // выполняете команду
        command.ExeсuteNonQuery();
    }
    else
    {
        label9.Visible = true;
        label9.Text = "Поля 'Cумма' , 'Дата' и 'Категории' должны быть заполнены!";
    }
}
```

Comment: Я добавил command.ExecuteNonQuery(); теперь выдает ошибку: